# How not to lose PHP $_POST variable data when another form $_POST happening?

Tags: php, post

Good evening,

I have an $_POST data what I process

```
$input_process = implode(',',$_POST['delay']);
```

Then I create a form

```
echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'"  method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Activate" name="activate_button"/>';
echo '</form>';
```

It will result a $_POST variable, with value: Active - $_POST['activate_button']

But then I lose the data in $_POST['delay'].

How can I store / keep the value(s) stored in the $_POST['delay'], even after the starting another $_POST event ( $_POST['activate_button']   )?

Comment: You can store it in a session

Comment: @TassMark Are you using the $input_process data within the page with the new form? Something like a delay timer before the "Activate" button is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in a session:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['input_process'] = implode(',',$_POST['delay']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add hidden field to your form and populate with $input_process value:

```php
echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'"  method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $input_process . '" name="delay"/>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Activate" name="activate_button"/>';
echo '</form>';
```

Alternative is to use $_SESSION but it is not the best way in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Is Your $_POST['delay'] an array ??

As Rob says you can store it in a session.
Or if you don't want to register a session variable, why not create hidden input field

```
<input type='hidden' name='delay' value='<?php echo $input_process; ?>' />
```

The best part, It will result in a directly accessible variable as $_POST['delay']

Comment: Thank you Devesh Sati! Yes, $_POST['delay'] is an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the value in a session or a cookie,if you want the values to be remembered for some time,

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['input_process'] = $_POST['delay'];

setcookie($delay, $_POST['delay'], time() + (86400 * 30));

//you can print these values this way

echo $_SESSION['input_process'];

echo $_COOKIE[$delay];

?>
```